# How to Implement Kotlin interface in Java Code?

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, interface

I have a project with Kotlin and Java code, actually I wan to implement a Kotlin interface like this:

```
interface BranchOfficeController{
  fun getBOs(): List<BO>
  fun getBOsById(id: Long) : Optional<BO>
}
```

An when I implemented into Java class like this:

```
public class BranchOfficeControllerImpl implements BranchOfficeController{
  ..
  stuff
  ..
}
```

Intellij does not show any error, everything looks fine, but when compiling it seems to me the following error.

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: Just import your interface `import package.BranchOfficeController` to your java class